# Need to resolve dependencies for installation

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm trying to install `librhythmbox-core8` but when I run the commands it fails.

### apt-get install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-rb-3.0 : Depends: librhythmbox-core8 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not installed
 rhythmbox : Depends: librhythmbox-core8 (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu2~ppa0) but it is not installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder : Depends: librhythmbox-core8 (>= 3.0) but it is not installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: librhythmbox-core8 (= 3.0.1-1ubuntu2~ppa0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

### apt-get -f install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-zeitgeist-2.0 python3-mako python3-markupsafe rhythmbox-plugins
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  librhythmbox-core8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  librhythmbox-core8
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/816 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 259967 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking librhythmbox-core8 (from .../librhythmbox-core8_3.0.1-1ubuntu2~ppa0_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core8_3.0.1-1ubuntu2~ppa0_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/librhythmbox-core.so.8.0.0', which is also in package librhythmbox-core7 3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core8_3.0.1-1ubuntu2~ppa0_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: how do i fix the dependencies ?

Comment: Read my answer, because this is a case where this is a package bug and we can't resolve it here.

Comment: @ThomasW. Sorry. I was typing the comment out and right before I posted my comment my browser froze. As soon as it posted I realized that there were already 3 comments. I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is because you have two versions of the rhythmbox package.

`librhythmbox-core7` is installed on your system, and you're trying to install `librhythmbox-core8`.

You need to manually remove `librhythmbox-core7` before you can install `librhythmbox-core8`.

```
sudo dpkg --remove librhythmbox-core7
sudo apt-get install librhythmbox-core8
```

Comment: Try the revised items I just did, see if that fixes it.

Comment: @ArK did the revised commands fix this?